# SQLite File Version Compatibility Across Android API Levels

Tags: android, sqlite, version, file-format

This question is regarding **SQLite file version** as it relates to **file format of the SQLite file** itself and compatibility across Android API levels.

Android OS comes prepackaged with a certain version of SQLite depending on API level, but this refers to version of SQLite library used, not file format:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/package-summary

According to SQLite documentation, database file format has not changed since 3.0 release in 2004:
[https://www.sqlite.org/formatchng.html#:~:text=But%20the%20most%20recent%20versions,though%20not%20necessarily%20forwards%20compatible](https://www.sqlite.org/formatchng.html#:%7E:text=But%20the%20most%20recent%20versions,though%20not%20necessarily%20forwards%20compatible).

However, I feel that documentation cited below is not exactly crystal clear on ***file format compatibility***:

> Since 2004, there have been enhancements to SQLite **such that newer
> database files are unreadable by older versions of the SQLite library**.
> But the most recent versions of the SQLite library should be able to
> read and write any older SQLite database file without any problems.
>
> In other words, since 2004 all SQLite releases have been backwards
> compatible, **though not necessarily forwards compatible**.

## Question:

**If SQLite database is created outside of Android using a newer SQLite library (e.g. Ver. 3.24), can this cause compatibility issues when this SQLite file is opened on Android with lower SQLite library version?**